# How do I get the UUID of a bundle?

Tags: entities

The getBundleInfo method returns only the machine name and label for bundles.  How do I get the UUID of each bundle, or of all bundles?

Comment: Looks like I'm able to get a list of my bundles and their UUIDs via a GET request to a jsonapi endpoint.  I still wonder how it might be done in PHP.

Comment: Can you say which REST API listing UUID?

Comment: @Ajay, the endpoint I used was... https://example.com/myentity_type/myentity_type -- if you install the jsonapi_extras module you will be able to find the relevant endpoint listed at admin/config/services/jsonapi

Comment: Can you check my answer and see if that suits you.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\uuid\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Class UUIDController.
 *
 * @package Drupal\uuid\Controller
 */
class UUIDController extends ControllerBase {

  public function uuidGet() {
    $uuid = [];
    $entity_type_definations = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions();
    /* @var $definition \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface */
    foreach ($entity_type_definations as $definition) {
      if ($definition instanceof ContentEntityType) {
        $content_types = \Drupal::entityManager()->getBundleInfo($definition->id());
        $entity_type = $definition->getBundleEntityType();
        if ($entity_type && $content_types) {
          foreach ($content_types as $type_id => $type) {
            $uuid[$entity_type][$type_id] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($type_id)->uuid();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return new JsonResponse($uuid);
  }

}
```

Above code will give UUID of all bundles and you can call this controller anywhere in your code like below, this will give all UUID's for bundles presented.

> Drupal\entity_type_clone\Controller\UUIDController::uuidGet()

To get a single UUID for specific bundle try below code:

> Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("ENTITY_TYPE")->load("BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME")->uuid();

Comment: A controller should return a Response. Why all of this instead of `Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node_type")->load("BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME")->uuid();`?

Comment: @Kevin Updated answer for controller response thanks for suggestion. As arnoldbird
  clearly mentioned he needs UUID of each bundle or all bundle irrespective of "Entity Type". That's I suggested a controller and listed there all UUID of each entity type with bundle.

Comment: I missed the part about getting all of the bundles, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME` with your bundle machine name.

```
Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node_type")->load("BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME")->uuid();
```

Or you can also load it like this:

```
Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::load("BUNDLE_MACHINE_NAME")->uuid();
```

Entities based on `EntityInterface` will have the `uuid()` method.

See [`EntityInterface::uuid`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Auuid/8.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method will be by adding UUID by editing views of entity listing.

Eg: if you want to find the UUID of content,

1. Edit the view admin/content
2. Add Field UUID
3. Save View

Navigate to admin/content to see uuid for corresponding content entity

Answer (score 0):

If you have [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, you can see the UUID by inspecting the development output of such content from the admin UI or debugging a variable.

[image]